# Help with Modeling Random Effects Model Interaction

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am having some trouble determining the correct modeling strategy for my research.

I have a sample of approximately 500 movie observations nested within approximately 250 franchises. The average number of movies per franchise is approximately 2, but the number of movies per franchise ranges from 1 to 14. About 140 franchises have only 1 observation.

I first thought about analyzing the data using a multilevel model, but the singleton groups worry me. Here is an example of the model I am trying to estimate:

```
BoxOfficeRevenue = 
   OpenTheaters + AwardWon + Budget + FranchiseBookBased
   + Budget*OpenTheaters + Budget*AwardWon
   + FranchiseBookBased*AwardWon + FranchiseBookBased*OpenTheaters
   + Controls
```

AwardWon is a dichotomous (0-1) variable
FranchiseBookBased is a dichotomous (0-1) variable

Should I continue down the mixed/multilevel path or are there other suggestions? Fixed effects will not work since it washes away the focal level 2 moderator.

Any literature support would be helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of your model?

Comment: Examine the interaction effects between Z (level 2 variable) and mutliple level 1 predictors on the outcome; I am examining the effects of individual movie characteristics (level 1) on box office performance, but these movies are all nested within franchises (level 2) with a franchise-level moderating variable of interest

Comment: You actually provide no example of your data and only a very abstract representation of a model with no description whatsoever of the outcome. It's not clear how the X's, the C's and Z1 are related to the 250 groups you mention at the start.

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect the variables: 

BoxOfficeRevenue = OpenTheaters + AwardWon + Budget + FranchiseBookBased + Budget*OpenTheaters + Budget*AwardWon + FranchiseBookBased*AwardWon + FranchiseBookBased*OpenTheaters + Controls

AwardWon is a dichotomous (0-1) variable
FranchiseBookBased is a dichotomous (0-1) variable

Comment: *FranchiseBookBased* is the variable with 250 levels?

Comment: Yes. Franchise is cluster variable with $250 groups